# How to load/parse huge xml data and arrange its order

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have a big xml file which I want to parse in different variables with C#.
The XML looks like this:

```
<PutDataRequest RequestId="XGR172DBES" MessageTime="2018-03-20T14:17:33.404+02:00" TransmissionComplete="true" TransmissionSuspended="false">
    <Positions EventTime="2017-07-15T15:10:13.280+02:00">
        <MetaData MatchId="MAT-1238TN" Type="pitch-size">
            <PitchSize X="125.00" Y="45.00"/>
        </MetaData>
        <FrameSet GameSection="secondHalf" MatchId="MAT-1238TN" TeamId="ZTU-012302" PersonId="OBJ-0054T8">
            <Frame N="132874" T="2017-07-15T15:55:35.680+02:00" X="3.66" Y="-35.02" S="0.00" D="0.00" A="0.00" M="67"/>
            <Frame N="132875" T="2017-07-15T15:55:36.680+02:00" X="3.68" Y="-36.02" S="0.00" D="0.00" A="0.00" M="67"/>

            ....
        </FrameSet>
        <FrameSet GameSection="secondHalf" MatchId="MAT-1238TN" TeamId="ZTU-012302" PersonId="OBJ-0016ZT">
                <Frame N="127912" T="2017-07-15T15:53:17.680+02:00" X="0.80" Y="-31.55" S="0.00" D="0.00" A="0.00" M="64"/>

                ...
        </FrameSet>
        <FrameSet GameSection="firstHalf" MatchId="MAT-1238TN" TeamId="ZTU-00134E" PersonId="OBJ-0012TZ">
            <Frame N="10001" T="2017-07-15T14:30:17.680+02:00" X="20.22" Y="10.92" S="0.00" D="0.00" A="0.00" M="1"/>

            ...
        </FrameSet>
```

The aim is to have for each frame all persons with there teamid and X,Y and S variables.
What's the best solution for this?
My problem is that I can't even open the file on my desktop computer properly because if I scroll down or up there to search something it always takes a while. That's why I'm afraid of just parsing it with XML Lynq because of the long loading time.
Also I don't know how it is the best way to parse it so I have the data in the order I like it to have (each frame with all persons and not each person for each half with its frames)

Hopefully you can help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "parsing it with XML Linq" Then use the `XmlSerializer`. But anyway how should any serializer maintain the order if it should not open the *complete* file? This surely takes time for a huge file, no matter *which* serializer you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing to the exact output that you desire. I believe the fastest way for you to do this would be to use XmlTextReader which is a forward only reader, and is very fast. Below is an example of how to use it; this may not exactly meet your requirements (again they are hard to understand), but it should give you a start.

My example gives you a list of all the people and their frames.

```
//define a couple of classes to hold people and frames
public class Person
{
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    public List<Frame> Frames { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Frames = new List<Frame>();
    }
}

public class Frame
{
    public string N { get; set; }
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
    public string S { get; set; }
}
```

Now we will read into the classes using XmlTextReader:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"c:\temp\frames.xml");
var people = new List<Person>();
var person = new Person();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            case "FrameSet":
                var id = reader.GetAttribute("PersonId");
                if (!people.Any(p => p.PersonId == id))
                {
                    person = new Person { PersonId = id, TeamId = reader.GetAttribute("TeamId") };
                    people.Add(person);
                }
                else
                {
                    person = people.First(p => p.PersonId == id);
                }
                break;
            case "Frame":
                var n = reader.GetAttribute("N");
                var x = reader.GetAttribute("X");
                var y = reader.GetAttribute("Y");
                var s = reader.GetAttribute("S");
                person.Frames.Add(new Frame { N = n, X = x, Y = y, S = s });
                break;                        
        }
    }
}
```